# what is wrong with interupt vector in assembly

Tags: assembly, avr, atmega

why changetime not called?
   i want to do some operation when the rising edge of int0 be true.
i set interupt and do allthing i think that the wrong are from the first lines from .org

```
.include "m32def.inc"
.ORG $00
RJMP define
.ORG $002
RJMP changetime
.ORG $40
.DB $0C,$0A,$21,$11
.ORG $100
.DB $FC,$60,$DA,$F2,$66,$B6,$BE,$E0,$FE,$F6
.ORG $200
.DB $FB,$F6,$F1,$E2,$C4

define:
LDI R20,246
LDI R24,$41
OUT GICR,R24
LDI R24,$40
OUT GICR,R16
SEI
LDI R24,$03
OUT MCUCR,R24
SBI DDRD,0
SBI DDRD,1
LDI R16,$04
OUT SPH,R16
LDI R16,$00
OUT SPL,R16

changetime:
LDI R20,$FF
CPI R21,5
BRNE dochangetime
LDI R21,0
RJMP exitchangetime
dochangetime:
LDI R31,$03
MOV R30,R21
LPM R20,Z
INC R21
LOPP:RJMP LOPP
exitchangetime:
RETI
```

but exactly never the pc go to changetime.

Comment: Have you enabled interrupts?

Comment: yes, i set i (SEI)

Comment: Your reset ISR falls through into `changetime`, is that what you really want?

Comment: Which MCU are you using? Have you also set the interrupt mask register?

Comment: @MargaretBloom i want when the PORTD.2 be true my changetime run

Comment: What is the value of R16? `OUT GICR,R16`

Comment: You need to write a complete question. We don't know 1) your exact MCU model 2) How you are planning to generate a falling edge on INT0 (this is how you programmed the INT0 pin) 3) why you took the decisions that are reflected in your code (why PORTD.2 is set as an output pin?). You also need to comment your code. "This is not working" and "I want this" won't help you (and us) a bit.

Comment: Why does the interrupt handler contain an infinte loop (`LOPP: RJMP LOPP`)? Are you sure you don't need to save (push) some registers ?

Comment: there is no loop in "define" block. So, the program execution falls through into "changetime" after start. After that it executes "reti", which leads to undefined results. Considering that you're initialized the stack pointer wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are somehow confused about external interrupts. There is a good tutorial about external interrupts for 8 bit AVR microcontrollers:

http://www.avr-tutorials.com/interrupts/The-AVR-8-Bits-Microcontrollers-External-Interrupts

First of all, since I don't know what you want to do I will give some general ideas how to solve your problem. You have defined your external interrupt directive here:

```
.ORG $002
RJMP changetime
```

This part says that an when an external interrupt happens (for $002 case it is external interrupt 0 ) jump to changetime. So to interrupt we should enable the bit 2 of PORTD. The External Interrupt 0 can be activated by the external pin INT0 if the SREG I-flag and the corresponding
interrupt mask are set. So if you want to change time externally you should enable the corresponding PIN.

Comment: If you add some comments and explain what you want to do, I can help better for your code.